# System clock 100x slow

Tags: windows-10, sleep, gpu, clock

I just encountered a baffling glitch.  I woke up my laptop (windows 10) from a weekend of sleeping (maybe hibernation), and noticed the clock was wrong.  It was 1:31 PM on Monday, but my computer claimed it to be about 12:27 AM on Tuesday.  Eh, maybe a network error.  Came back to my desk a few minutes later, looked at it a bit more....  At some point I noticed it was 1:43 PM, but my computer claimed 12:31 AM, as if it had lost 8 of the past 12 minutes.  I went to https://currentmillis.com/ and to my surprise, the milliseconds counter was only very slowly increasing; about 10 ms every second.  (I took a screenshot about every second for maybe 10 seconds, which I can provide if necessary, but I don't think it'll provide any more useful information.)  Actually, IT'S DOING IT AGAIN.  And I've started a java test program, in an infinite while loop printing `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `Thread.sleep(1000);`, it's exhibiting similar behavior - it pauses for *several* seconds, then spits out a clump of timestamps.  Even *between* clumps, though, only milliseconds pass.  I've attached a log to the end of my post.  At some point, it started working like normal.  I notice, in retrospect, there were a few seconds in there were the time jumped backwards a few hours, *nearly* to the correct time.  Another thing I've noticed (it's happening again, now) is that during the weird slow times, Firefox, Outlook, and the Desktop Windows Manager are using 100% of the GPU.  100% GPU appears correlate exactly with the time shenanigans, as best I can tell without more accurate records.

Ultimately, I wish to know why this happened, or how it feasibly COULD have happened.  Rebooting the computer caused the clock to stop exhibiting the strange behavior, so I don't need to know how to end an occurrence of the glitch, but I would have thought this kind of behavior nearly impossible in the first place.  Many server programs rely on timeouts, and if the clock effectively stops for 13 min, it could cause a wide variety of other problems.  I doubt I'll be able to reproduce the issue, so further debugging is infeasible.  Essentially, I want to know if anyone has heard of anything similar, or can come up with a plausible theory based on their knowledge of the deeper workings of Windows' system time mechanism (which I don't have).

Sample of timestamps logged:

```
1553575488576
1553575488584
1553575488591
1553575488599
1553575488606
1553575488614
1553575488621
1553575488628
1553575488636
1553575488643
1553575488651
1553575488658
1553575488665
1553575488673
1553575488680
1553575488688
1553575488695
1553575488703
1553575488710
1553575488717
1553575488725
1553575488732
1553575488740
1553575488747
1553575488754
1553575488762
1553575488769
1553575488777
1553575488784
1553575488791
1553575488799
1553575488806
1553575488814
1553575488821
1553575488828
1553575488836
1553575488843
1553575488851
1553575488858
1553575488865
1553575488873
1553575488880
1553575488888
1553575488895
1553575488902
1553575488910
1553575488917
1553575488925
1553575488932
1553575488940
1553575488947
1553575488955
1553575488962
1553575488969
1553575488977
1553575488984
1553575488992
1553575488999
1553575489006
1553575489014
1553575489021
1553575489029
1553575489036
1553575489044
1553575489051
1553575489058
1553575489066
1553575489073
1553575489081
1553575489088
1553575489095
1553575489103
1553575489110
1553575489118
1553575489125
1553575489132
1553575489140
1553575489147
1553575489155
1553575489162
1553575489169
1553575489177
1553575489184
1553575489192
1553575489199
1553575489206
1553575489214
1553575489221
1553575489229
1553575489236
1553575489243
1553575489251
1553575489258
1553575489265
1553575489273
1553575489280
1553575489288
1553575489295
1553575489303
1553575489310
1553575489317
1553575489325
1553575489332
1553575489340
1553575489347
1553575489354
1553575489362
1553575489369
1553575489376
1553575489384
1553575489391
1553575489399
1553575489406
1553575489413
1553575489421
1553575489428
1553575489436
1553575489443
1553575489450
1553575489458
1553575489465
1553575489473
1553575489480
1553575489487
1553575489495
1553575489502
1553575489510
1553575489517
1553575489524
1553575489532
1553575489539
1553575489547
1553575489554
1553575489561
1553575489569
1553575489576
1553575489584
1553575489591
1553575489598
1553575489606
1553575489613
1553575489621
1553575489628
1553575489635
1553575489643
1553575489650
1553575489658
1553575489665
1553575489672
1553575489680
1553575489687
1553575489695
1553575489702
1553575489709
1553575489717
1553575489724
1553575489732
1553575489739
1553575489746
1553575489754
1553575489761
1553575489769
1553575489776
1553575489783
1553575489791
1553575489798
1553575489806
1553575489813
1553575489820
1553575489828
1553575489835
1553575489843
1553575489850
1553575489857
1553575489865
1553575489872
1553575489880
1553575489887
1553575489895
1553575489902
1553575489909
1553575489917
1553575489924
1553575489932
1553575489939
1553575489946
1553575489954
1553537091156
1553537092160
1553537093161
1553537094162
1553537095163
1553537096164
1553537097164
1553537098165
1553537099174
1553537100193
1553537101196
1553537102209
1553537103214
1553537104215
1553537105216
1553537106216
1553576225618
1553576226620
1553576227623
1553576228626
1553576229628
1553576230630
1553576231632
1553576232636
1553576233639
1553576234641
1553576235644
1553576236646
1553576237648
1553576238650
```

Edit: I collected more data and turned it into a graph.  The blue line is the progression of time, as counted by trying to sysout currentTimeMillis every second.  When the clock was glitching out, the logs would clump into groups of seven or so, but would still average around one line a second, so I think you can treat the x-axis as being in seconds.  (I've subtracted the first timestamp, and clipped everything to 41M, so the patterns in the graph are visible.  I do not believe any information I removed was particularly helpful.)  Eyeballing the graph, it looks like what was happening was that in cycles of approximately 18 min, the clock would be normal for 5 min (albeit ~11 hours ahead), then 13 min of very slow clock, then a brief dip backwards many hours, then a jump forward to a point as if the slow segment never occurred.  (When I worked out the average rate across one cycle, I got 1003 ms/sample, though I'll grant that the connection between recorded sample rate and ACTUAL sample rate is based on my own estimation.  I nevertheless believe the clock rate to average to the correct rate, over the course of a cycle.)
[image: Clock glitch graph]
Edit: FYI, I've just experienced the glitch again today.  Probably relevant: I left my laptop asleep for about 5 days, then it exhibited the problem when next I turned it on.  Also note: Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1803, build 17134.590.

Comment: Does this behavior exhibit itself while in Safe Mode?  Edit your question and include the vital information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Even a normal reboot appears to fix the problem.  I'm not asking how to fix it, though; I'm more interested in why it happened in the first place - if this happened on a server, for instance, it could be catastrophic.  I'm editing my post to include a graph; just a second.

Comment: I would assume the reason was your system CPU usage was 100%.  Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound Probably not the CPU.  My screenshots indicate that many of the times during the glitch had the CPU at small values, such as 3%, which is less than the 8.3% needed to max out even a single core.  Disk access and memory usage were likewise normal.  GPU was the only odd value: as near as I can measure, 100% during the glitch, and low when not glitching.  Also, I've tried to add a paragraph clarifying what I'm asking.

Comment: Even if it were the CPU, though, in my experience the whole system becomes unresponsive before the clock stops working, and in those cases I suspect that it's merely that the UI can't update the displayed time, rather than the clock itself failing.  I cannot test this, though, as everything becomes unresponsive, rendering it somewhat moot, anyway.

Comment: First, kudos on an odd but well-documented problem. I would check for firmware  and driver updates, if you have not already, and I would also suspect that if updated firmware and drivers are not available, and if your computer is under a warranty, you should contact them. This may be a software issue, but I think it's more likely to be a hardware issue.